# I want to prevent duplicate string output

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I wrote the code like this.

```
sentence = input("문자열 입력 : ")
sentence = sentence.lower()
sentence = sentence.replace(' ','')
def count(string):
    for i in range(0, len(sentence)):
        a = sentence[i]
        b = sentence.count(a)
        i += 1
        print("%s : %s" %(a, b))
    return 
count(sentence)
```

But I want to print it out once if there is already the same alphabet. For example, if I input the word 'APPLE, apple!', the code I wrote print 
`a : 2
 p : 4
 p : 4
 l : 2
 e : 2
 , : 1
 a : 2
 p : 4
 p : 4
 l : 2
 e : 2
 ! : 2`, but I want to print like this.
`a : 2 
 p : 4 
 l : 2 
 e : 2
 , : 1
 ! : 1`

I think

```
for i in range(0, len(sentence)):
  a = sentence[i]
  b = sentence.count(a)
  i += 1
```

is wrong, but I don't know how to fix it.

What should I do???

Comment: You could just use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 0):

first thing to note is that the argument you pass to the function (string) and the variable you process
inside the function are different. So, the argument should be changed to sentence.

next, you could use a dictionary to keep score:

```
def count(sentence):
    count_dictionary = {}
    for character in sentence:
        count_dictionary[character] = sentence.count(character)

    for a, b in count_dictionary.items():
        print(a, ' : ', b)
    return count_dictionary
```

Comment: If I try it the way you suggested, it is printed in dict format. But, I want to print it  "a : 2 (ENTER) p : 4 (ENTER) l : 2 (Enter) e : 2 (ENTER) , : 1 (ENTER)  ! : 1"